# Threaded ListView for Android

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm working on an app that involves displaying comments from a website.  These comments are threaded on the original site, so I'd like to replicate that experience within the app.  I know that Android has an ExpandableListView, but it only does two levels and I was hoping for more.

Each top-level content would be aligned to the left.  Replies would be indented by x units, replies to the reply would be indented x*2 units, etc.

Additionally, I'd like the ability for the user (or even the application code) to minimize/maximize threads.  This would be particularly useful if the first comment has 8724 replies - you could just minimize the original comment instead of scrolling endlessly until you reach the second top-level comment.

What is the best way to present this multi-level list to the user?  Are there any native/third-party classes/libraries I can use, or would I be better of coding this list in HTML and displaying that to the user instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think you should use a tree for displaying thread. Device screens are too small for this kind of widget. I would prefer multiple activities for displaying different levels of the thread. But I'm not a UI designer so my opinion may be far from the ideal solution.

**EDIT**: Here's an open-source tree-view widget: http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/.

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned that this app is for tablets only.  I'll be using a fragment to display comments on the right 2/3rds of the screen.